# Crop overlay to mark the scan field

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, surfaceview, crop, barcode-scanner

I implemented a barcode scanner in our Xamarin app. To implement the scanner I followed this tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-qr-code-reader-by-mobile-camera/

So, I have a SurfaceView, a CameraSource and a BarcodeDetector. Now I want to crop the camera preview to say the scanner where the barcode in which we have to scan because it is possible that the source from which we can have more than one barcode.

I think this will work with Simple Crop View (or something similar) but I don't how to implement it.
All solutions found here are not working or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to acheve it like this GIF?

[image]

If so, you could achieve it with `ZXing.Net.Mobile`
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile

There is my demo
https://github.com/851265601/Scanebarcode

**Update: If you still want to use the solution like the blew link**

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-qr-code-reader-by-mobile-camera/

I changed the layout like following code. I usd `FramLayout`, `SurfaceView` was coverd by other raylout just like `LinearLayout` or `relativelayout`

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/cameraView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#953399ff"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#953399ff"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlscan"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/area_above_left" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/area_above_right" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/area_below_left" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/area_below_right" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#953399ff"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#953399ff"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cameraView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please focus Camera to QR Code"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Exactly. This is what I want. But the problem is, that we don't want to use Zxing.Net.Mobile because the scanning results are not very good.

Comment: @r3d007, If you still want to use `Google Play Services - Vision `, I wirte a new layout by your needs(I updated my answer, you can refer to it), this layout could achieve the result, my mobile phone 's VPN is expired, I cannot connect to google, so I cannot test it for you.